# How can I set the rightmost bit of a pointer to 1 in C

Tags: c, pointers, bit-manipulation

I need to tag the address of an int pointer with a 1 in the rightmost bit and store that address somewhere. For example the address at 0x10 would become 0x11.

I have tried doing

```
int* addr = some_pointer;
int* tagged = (int*) (addr | 0x00000001);
```

but I get error: invalid operands to binary expression ('int *' and 'int'). How could I go about doing this?

Comment: Cast to `uintptr_t`, perform bit arithmetic, cast it back to `int*`.

Comment: Please don't tag pointers, just don't.....

Comment: As @chux points out in his answer, this is undefined behavior.  The real-world impact of using that final pointer is likely to be a `SIGBUS` or `SIGSEGV` on many architectures.

Answer (score 7):

> How can I set the rightmost bit of a pointer to 1?

C99/C11 provides *optional* integer types `(u)intptr_t` to covert a `void*` pointer to an integer and then back to a pointer.  This round trip results in a pointer that is equal in *value* to the original.   It may or may not have the same bit pattern as the original pointer.

```
#include <stdint.h>
int i = 42;
int* addr = &i;
void *vptr = addr;
uintptr_t uptr = (uintptr_t) vptr;

// Set least significant bit.
uintptr_t uptr1 = uptr | 1;
// or one-liner
uintptr_t uptr1 = ((uintptr_t) (void *) &i) | 1;
```

<strike>There is no print specifier for `(u)intptr_t`, so</strike> code can cast to the widest type for display purposes

```
printf("%p --> %ju --> %ju\n", vptr, (uintmax_t) uptr, (uintmax_t) uptr1); 
// or use macros from <inttypes.h>
printf("%p --> %" PRIuPTR " --> %" PRIuPTR "\n", vptr, uptr, uptr1);
```

As long as OP only needs to store the value as an integer, no problem. `(u)intptr_t` values that originate from a valid pointer can convert back to a matching pointer type with no problem.

So far so good, yet OP may want to use the manipulated value.

Now the trick is that `uptr1` may or may not covert to a valid `void *` pointer.  Even if it  does convert to a valid  `void *` pointer, the conversion to an `int *` may or may not work.  These two steps are beyond the C spec - undefined behavior.

```
// UB
void *vptr1 = (void *) uptr1;
printf("%p\n", vptr1); 
int *iptr1 = vptr1;
```

If code makes it this far, attempting to de-reference this new pointer, it is also UB.

```
printf("%d\n", *iptr1);       // UB, good luck
```

Comment: It takes a pretty discerning eye to focus on the word "*optional*" at the end of Section 7.20.1.4 (C11 draft).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin On uncommon platforms without `(u)intptr_t`, using `(u)intmax_t` might do in a pinch, but I think code should simply fail compilation that lack `(u)intptr_t` to perform this _unusual_ coding goal.

Comment: I had never thought forward through the "What can you do with a `uniptr_t` value later"? That was great discussion. It's like the type was provided to allow handling a few corner-case int-to-pointer-and-back conversions, but not much else. I guess I haven't run into those cases yet. Good job.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `[u]intptr_t` is very useful in passing a simple `int` value to a child thread via `pthread_create()`.

Comment: Did you mean to use `%ju` to print the `uintmax_t` values?

Comment: @DavidBowling Yes, `"%ju"` was intended.  My keyboard was responding to what I typed rather than what I thought.  Should have used a [neural scan interface](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Neural_scan_interface).

Comment: Yes, that happens to me all the time; I must get one of those. Now, if I could only visit a Circuit City in the year 2367....

Answer (score 1):

As stated in comments, you need to convert the pointer to integral type **explicitly**:

```
int* addr = some_pointer;
int* tagged = (int*) ((uintptr_t)addr | 0x00000001);
```

Or shorter:

```
int* tagged = (int*) ((uintptr_t)some_pointer | 0x1);
```

You may need to include `<stdint.h>` in order to use macro define `uintptr_t`.

---

### If you want to know why...

First, bit or operator `|` only allows **Integral Types** as operands.

> A bit about the type categories of C in [C89 draft](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html). (I didn't check C99, C11)
>
> - **Integral Type** = char, signed and unsigned integer types, enumerated types.
> - **Arithmetic Type** = **Integral Type** and **Floating Type**
> - **Scalar Type** = **Arithmetic Type** and **Pointer Type**

So pointer is not an **Integral Type**. However, this is not enough to explain the error.

If there is an `implicit conversion` rule that automatically converts a pointer type to an integral type, you will be ok. (FYI: `implicit conversion` is a set of type conversion rules that will be applied to source automatically)

However, no such rule exists. So, you saw the error.

But sometimes, we really need to do math operations on a pointer variable. This is why we need `explicit conversion`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to do this that will likely annoy your compiler is to use *address of* operator `int* ptr = &var;`.

Below is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int val = 5;
    int* ptr = &val;
    int* addr = (int*)((int)&ptr | 0x00000001);
    printf("address val: %x, ptr: %x, &ptr: %x, addr: %x \n", &val, ptr, &ptr, addr);
    return 0;
}
```

The output of which is:

```
address val: 5880dacc, ptr: 5880dacc, &ptr: 5880dac0, addr: 5880dac1
```